# How to center element in jetpack compose without using weight?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following composable

```
Box (modifier = Modifier
        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
        .then(modifier)) {
    Row {
        CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically))
        Column {
            Text(text = "Title", fontSize = 24.sp, color = Color.White)
            Text(text = "Subtitle", fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.LightGray)
        }
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        ) { ... }            
    }
}
```

I want to horizontally align controls in the following way:

- Left align `CircularProgressIndicator` (align to the parent left)
- Center align `Column`
- Right align `Button` (align to the parent right)

I can easily do it by adding `weight(1f)` to the column but this causes the `Box` to increase the width to occupy all available space. I don't want that.

**Why?**

Because this composable is used in two places: In one place is used with "wrap content" width, in the other place it's used with "fill available space" width. The center align for the column is useful on "fill available space" mode.

If I use `weight`, I cannot use "wrap content" as far I tested.

**EDIT**

if I use `weight(1f, false)` this is what I see when `Box` is presented to fill available width

```
----------------------------------------------------
| CPI | COL | BUT |           EMPTY SPACE          |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

you should apply following changes.
first you should change your **Row** like this:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    ...
}
```

then you should change your **Column** like this:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    ...
}
```

and it should be as you described.

[image]

Comment: I don't see this working as I want unfortunately. I said on the question that this composable works in two modes: 1) wrap content 2) fill entire screen width. Adding your changes breaks the mode "wrap content" as far I tested, the composable covers the entire width always.